# Is the set of all rational additive partitions of a rational number countable?

Tags: number-theory, set-theory, rational-numbers, integer-partitions

We usually call additive partitions the set, we call it $P$, of all the ways to write a positive integer $n$ as a sum of positive integers. Formally:

\begin{equation}
P_n = \left\{ (a_1 ,...,a_n)\in\mathbb{N}^n:\sum_{0<k\leq n} a_k =n\right\} \quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}
\end{equation}

I was thinking about writing any rational number as a sum of rational numbers, and define the set of rational additive partitions as:

\begin{equation}
P_q = \left\{ (p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} :p_n\in\mathbb{Q},\quad\sum_{k>0} p_k =q\right\} \quad \forall q\in\mathbb{Q}
\end{equation}

For example, if $q=1$ then the sequences $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\ldots),(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{6},0,0,\ldots),\ldots$ belong to $P_1$, because $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1, \quad\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{6}=1$ etc...

This set is certainly infinite, but I was wondering if it was countable. My guess is that it is countable $\forall q$, because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, but I don't know how to prove it. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This set is uncountable. To see this, consider

$$
q=\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty2^{-\ell}q\;.
$$

The (infinitely many) terms are rational numbers. Now take the uncountable set of infinite binary sequences (i.e. binary sequences that are not eventually zero). This is uncountable since it essentially corresponds to binary representations of real numbers in $[0,1]$; the restriction to infinite sequences merely excludes the countably many finite sequences. For each such binary sequence $b_k$, traverse the sequence and let $p_k$ be the next term in the above series if $b_k=1$, and $0$ if $b_k=0$. This yields uncountably many different sequences $p_k$ of rational numbers, all of which sum to $q$.

Comment: Right! How did I not see it... Thanks!

Comment: As you've defined them, none of these sequences $<p_k>$ sum to $q$ (except the one corresponding to $<1>$) and most will have irrational sums. I assume you mean to start with the partial sums $\sum_{\ell=1}^k 2^{-\ell}q$ and then take the differences between successive terms where $b_k = 1$ ?

Comment: @DavidHartley: I don't understand the distinction that you're making. The differences between successive partial sums are just the terms of the series. Note that $\ell$ isn't $k$; it only increases by $1$ for every $b_k$ that's $1$ (at least that's what I meant to express by "let $p_k$ be the next term in the above series").

Comment: @DavidHartley: Ah, perhaps I see what you mean – you want to add all the terms up to $k$ all at once when $b_k=1$? You can do it that way, too – it doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm just trying to clarify how you're doing it. As you've written it, the sequence $<p_k>$ is the sequence $<s^{-k}q>$ with some terms replaced with zeros, and so in general does not sum to $q$. Leaving out the zero terms doesn't alter the sum. When I suggest the differences between successive partial sums I said "where $b_k = 1$". These will be the sums of the terms of the original series between positions corresponding to $b_k =1$. I.e each $p_k$ will be the sum of a finite subset of the original sequence. If this isn't what you intended then I don't know what is.

Comment: A simpler approach may be to say let $\{P_n | n \in \mathbb N \}$ be a partition of $\mathbb N$ into disjoint subsets and let $p_k = \sum \{2^{-l}q|l \in P_k\}$. There are uncountably many such partitions, giving distinct sequences all with sum $q$.

Comment: @DavidHartley: It seems you didn't understand my above comment. There's no sequence $s^{-k}q$, it's $2^{-\ell}q$, and as I emphasized above, $\ell$ isn't $k$, so $p_k$ is not $2^{-\ell}q$ with some terms replaced by zero.

Comment: So what is $p_k$?  Perhaps if we make it more concrete: if $<b_k> = <1,0,0,1,1,0,\dots>$ what are$p_1$, $p_2$?

Comment: Good idea (to make it more concrete). In that case, $p_1=2^{-1}q$, $p_2=p_3=0$, $p_4=2^{-2}q$, $p_5=2^{-3}q$, $p_6=0,\ldots$. Suggestions how to formulate that more clearly are welcome.

Comment: Aha, I understand you now. I thought you were dropping the $k$th term when $b_k = 0$, but you're moving it on to a later $k$. This does indeed give a distinct sequence summing to $q$, but it's just the original values in the original order with extra $0$s interspersed, not what is usually meant by a different partition. . (Continued)

Comment: My variation was that the terms where $b_k = 0$ should be added to the next one where $b_k =1$. In the above example $2^{-1},(2^{-2} + 2^{-3} + 2^{-4}), 2^{-5}, (2^{-6} + \dots), \dots$ (letting $q=1$). This will always give a strictly decreasing sequence of positive rationals, and the correspondence with the b-sequences is 1-1